# Como criar playlist de vídeo no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Estou tentando criar uma *playlist* de vídeos no Delphi, para tocar os vídeos pelo *MediaPlayer*, porém, não executa todos os vídeos escolhidos, apenas o primeiro que roda, vejam o código:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  i:integer;
  Cont: Integer;
begin
  Cont := 0;
  if OpenDialog3.Execute  then
  begin
    for i := 0 to OpenDialog3.Files.count -1 do
      ListBox1.Items.Add(OpenDialog3.Files[i]);
    ListBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
    MediaPlayer1.FileName := ListBox1.Items[listbox1.ItemIndex];
    MediaPlayer1.Open;
    MediaPlayer1.Play;
  end;
end;
```

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Estou tentando criar uma playlist de vídeos no delphi, para tocar os
>   vídeos pelo mediaplayer e não executa todos os vídeos escolhidos,
>   apenas o primeiro que roda...

Isso acontece porque antes de definir o arquivo no MediaPlayer, o índice é alterado para *0*, é necessário remover a linha `ListBox1.ItemIndex`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  i, Cont: integer;
begin
  Cont := 0;
  if OpenDialog3.Execute  then
  begin
    for i := 0 to OpenDialog3.Files.count -1 do
      ListBox1.Items.Add(OpenDialog3.Files[i]);
    //ListBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
    MediaPlayer1.FileName := ListBox1.Items[listbox1.ItemIndex];
    MediaPlayer1.Open;
    MediaPlayer1.Play;
  end;
end;
```

**Atualização**

1. Crie uma variável global chamada `VideoAtual`:

   ```
   var
     Form1: TForm1;
     VideoAtual: Integer = 0;
   ```
2. Popule o `Listbox` com o método abaixo:

   ```
   procedure CriarPlayList;
   var
     I: integer;
   begin
     if OpenDialog1.Execute = False then exit;

     for I := 0 to OpenDialog1.Files.count -1 do
       ListBox1.Items.Add(OpenDialog1.Files[I]);
     ListBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
     MediaPlayer1.FileName := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
     MediaPlayer1.Open;
     MediaPlayer1.Play;
   end;
   ```
3. Para executar o vídeo, use o método abaixo:

   ```
   procedure ExecutarVideo(Indice: integer);
   begin
     if Indice >= ListBox1.Items.Count then begin
       VideoAtual := 0;
       Indice := 0;
     end;
     ListBox1.ItemIndex := Indice;
     MediaPlayer1.Close;
     MediaPlayer1.FileName := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
     MediaPlayer1.Open;
     MediaPlayer1.Play;
   end;
   ```
4. No evento `Onclick` do `MediaPlayer`, adicione o código:

   ```
   case Button of
      btNext: begin
         VideoAtual := VideoAtual + 1;
         ExecutarVideo(VideoAtual);
      end;
      btPrev: begin
         VideoAtual := VideoAtual - 1;
         ExecutarVideo(VideoAtual);
      end;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Continua sem rodar os vídeos adicionados, roda somente 1 e para.

Comment: @RenatoSouza Você seleciona antes o vídeo no `ListBox`?

Comment: o código é para não selecionar, ele deve pegar os itens do listbox1 e colocar na linha do player, mesmo eu executando o OpenDialog e depois selecionando não vai.

Comment: @RenatoSouza Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Amigo, agradeço sua imensa ajuda. Mas como sou iniciante, estou quebrando a cabeça pra saber onde coloco esses código, onde eu populo. Pode me ajuda senão for pedir muito. @qmechanik

Comment: @RenatoSouza Disponha. Veja [**esse exemplo**](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01498611817648685732). Criei ele no Delphi XE3, se você estiver usando uma versão muito antiga, talvez não consiga compilar ele, mas basta olhar o código.

Comment: @RenatoSouza Se funcionar, marque a resposta como aceita clicando no ✓ abaixo dos votos. =)

Comment: @qmwchanik Ele roda todos os vídeos que seleciono quando clico em buscar vídeos? Não rodou aqui, roda apenas 1 e pronto, não pula para os próximos.

Comment: Segue download do meu projeto. https://mega.co.nz/#!fFh3Rb5R!4QAicX8m7lxV2AAd5V9y8vGs6gfNAmbSv5Ra5pVztyA

Comment: @RenatoSouza Modifiquei aquele meu exemplo, [**veja aqui**](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08471276724863652986), basta clicar no "Criar PlayList" somente. Testei com músicas.

Comment: valeu amigo, deu certo, agora vou implementar para rodar as imagens junto e pronto. Valeu

Comment: sabe como posso fazer esse player pegar a lista de vídeos de um arquivo de texto, no txt eu tenho os caminhos um em baixo do outro e dai quero jogar eles direto, sem precisar abrir o opendialog.

Comment: @RenatoSouza Bom, eu acho que você pode colocar o caminho das imagens numa *array* e no *Timer* você vai colocando as imagens num componente `TImage`. Se não conseguir fazer isso, crie [uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) que eu tento ajudar melhor.

Comment: como faço pra poder rodar os vídeos sem precisar usar o opendialog, eu vou adicionar os vídeos por um txt externo.

Comment: @RenatoSouza Basta você ler linha por linha do *txt*, primeiramente você vai ter que abri-lo usando `AssignFile`, daí num *loop* você lê linha-a-linha usando o `Readln`. Se não conseguir fazer isto, [crie uma nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) daí tento responder melhor.